# How to send OTP to a custom to a user in custom userstore (The database has only one table)

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have made a custom userstore by overriding the UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager class, based on this article https://nishothan-17.medium.com/custom-user-store-manager-for-wso2-identity-server-5-11-0-6e23a4ddf1bb .  My database has one table which has the username, password, email, name, and phone number.

I was able to authenticate successfully. However, I am unable to send the OTP to the users phone number. Can anyone please guide me on how to send OTP to the user? Which properties do I have to set or override? Any help would be highly appreciated.

I could not find any documentation on this so far.

Comment: Did you try this - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/configuring-sms-otp/?

Comment: Yes, But that is a simple configuration. My requirement is to do SMS OTP from a custom user store. The userstore has only a single table. I think in my custom userclass the mobile claim is not being set. I could not find any documentation on how to programmatically set a claim.

Answer (score 1):

1. In order to send the SMS OTP to the user, there should be a valid mobile number in the user's profile.
2. For that you need to update the mobile claim's mapped attribute accordingly.

- Refer to https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/dialects/edit-claim-mapping/ and go to mobile claim configs. Then update the mapped attributes section.
- If you connect the custom userstore as your PRIMARY userstore, change the Mapped Attribute to the DB table's column name(phone number as per the question) respective to the PRIMARY userstore domain.
- If you are connecting this custom userstore as a secondary userstore, add another mapped attribute for the secondary userstore domain and put the DB table's column name.
- NOTE: Since you have only one table in the userstore and mobile number is available as a column in that table I mentioned to use that column name as the mapped attribute. Then you have to add additional DB queries under advance configurations to retrieve that data from DB.
  [image]

3. Then, you have to override `public Map<String, String> getUserPropertyValuesWithID(String userID, String[] propertyNames, String profileName) throws UserStoreException` method in your custom userstore manager. You have to invoke your custom DB query inside this overridden method to retrieve the user attributes.

- Here is the reference to the default uniqueIDJDBCUserstoreManager's method implementation:
  https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/09b67404ec8f4dc2e19d0d730f33c91441c1c63b/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/jdbc/UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager.java#L437
- Once http://wso2.org/claims/mobile claim value of the user is requested in [SMS OTP flow](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-sms-otp/blob/c91b09d9274972d9a02485bb376c175baa43fa4d/component/authenticator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/authenticator/smsotp/SMSOTPUtils.java#L199), the Abstractuserstore manager resolves the mappend attribute of the claim and handed over to the relevant userstore manager to resolve the properly value.

Comment: I am overriding the function with hardcore values. This should ideally set the mobile claim value. Is this the right way? The function name and code is mentioned below.
  public Map<String, String> getUserPropertyValuesWithID(String userID, String[] propertyNames, String profileName)
            throws UserStoreException 
--------------------------------------
String[] propertyNamesSorted = propertyNames.clone();
        Arrays.sort(propertyNamesSorted);
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
         map.put("mobile", "009234341555868");
                        return map;

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to the SMS-OTP as a second factor authentication. You can refer to this document [1].

And do you have any error trace to see if there are any specific issues to fix?

**Refer**:
[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/mfa/2fa-sms-otp/

Comment: My requirement is to do SMS OTP from a custom user store. The userstore has only a single table. I think in my custom userclass the mobile claim is not being set. I could not find any documentation on how to programmatically set a claim.